# Proof of theorem of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am currently in the process of self teaching myself some graph theory (I'm a CS student) and I've come across the following theorem in the Cambridge GT notes:

[image]

I am struggling to see the trivial implication, I'm sure I'm missing something easy, but can anyone explain this formally?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ have a matching of deficiency $d$. To make things easier to see, remove all the edges that aren't part of the matching.

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. We know that $d$ of the vertices in $X$ are unmatched. Since $A$ is a subset of $X$, at most $d$ of the vertices in $A$ are unmatched, leaving at least $|A|-d$ matched.

Since the edges in a matching must be independent, each matched vertex is adjacent to a distinct vertex of $Y$, giving us that $|\Gamma(A)|=\text{number of vertices in $A$ that are matched} \geq |A|-d$.

If we add the other edges back in then $\Gamma(A)$ certainly isn't going to get any smaller, so we must have $|\Gamma(A)| \geq |A|-d$ as required.